# VBA read excel file has "Subscription out of range" problem when file is opened first

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing vba to read data from an excel file. It works perfect when this source file is not opened.

However, if the source file is opened first, and then run this code, it will give me error of "Subscripion out of range".

Interested thing is that, if i opened my code file first, then open this source file, it runs no problem and source file will closed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReadDetail()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 13

        Dim xlspath As String
        Dim WB As Workbook
        Dim SALES_ORDER As Range        
        Set SALES_ORDER = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SO Details").Range("C" & i + 3)

        xlspath = "P:\Scheduling\Purchasing Schedule REV2.xlsx"
        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(xlspath, True, True)
        SALES_ORDER.Value = WB.Worksheets("Active").Range("AA22").Value

        WB.Close False
        Set WB = Nothing

    Next i    

 End Sub
```

Comment: (You're missing the `arr2` declaration) -  What line throws the error?

Comment: I simplify the code for shorter lines. There is a arr2 in my code. problem coming from: SALES_ORDER.Value = WB.Worksheets("Active").Range("AA22").Value.

Comment: We can't debug code we can't see, and you shortened it too much. Please [edit] your post to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Edit 1:  I saw where you were using "ThisWorkbook" instead of your declared object, which was "WB".

You are declaring the range before declaring the Workbook.  I'm assuming that when you have the workbook open it the range value is nulled out because you declare the workbook then you declare and set the range and then you set the workbook value. Try declaring and setting the range after you open the workbook. You can also put some conditional logic to not open the workbook if it's already open.

```
xlspath = "P:\Scheduling\Purchasing Schedule REV2.xlsx"
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(xlspath, True, True)
Dim SALES_ORDER As Range        
Set SALES_ORDER = WB.Sheets("SO Details").Range("C" & i + 3)
SALES_ORDER.Value = WB.Worksheets("Active").Range("AA22").Value
```

Comment: Tried, but It doesn't work, still give same problem at SALES_ORDER.Value = WB.Worksheets("Active").Range("AA22").Value

Comment: I changed the code slightly on the range to use "WB" instead of ThisWorkbook.

Comment: ThisWorkbook is the workbook that contains the code, then the code read data from  outside source file, what's why i use thisworkbook to seperate.

Comment: Then you need to declare the other workbook and indicate that the range comes from that workbook.  That's where your problem is.

Comment: Thanks.I declared range varable and set it to “”ThisWorkbook“” because it is the destination， for the value that coming from WB, i didn't declair it, i just use WB.Worksheets("Active").Range("AA22").Value to pass value to ThisWorkbook.